# jquery selecting elements and removing classes with partial class names

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following piece of JQuery code which searches an html document for instances of elements with the class `<xyz>-annotation-invisible` and replaces it with `<xyz>-annotation-visible`. The catch is that if a particular element already has class `<abc>-annotation-visible`, then I want to remove all classes of the form `*-annotation-visible` and `*-annotation-invisible` and replace them with the class `multiple-annotation-visible`. How can I check if a particular element already has `<abc>-annotation-visible`?

```
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const annotationTypes = urlParams.get('annotypes').split(',');
const multipleVisibleClass = "multiple-annotation-visible";

$(document).ready(function () {
  for (var i=0; i<annotationTypes.length; i++)
  {
    var annotype = annotationTypes[i];
    var annotationVisibleClass = `${annotype}-annotation-visible`;
    var annotationInvisibleClass = `${annotype}-annotation-invisible`;

    var elem = $(`.${annotationInvisibleClass}`);
    if (elem.hasClass(anyVisibleClass)) # not sure how to do this part
    {
      elem.removeClass(anyVisibleClass);
      elem.addClass(multipleVisibleClass);
    }
    else
    {
      elem.addClass(annotationVisibleClass);
    }
    elem.removeClass(annotationInvisibleClass);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`is()`](https://api.jquery.com/is/#is-selector) and the [attribute ends with selecor](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) :

```js
let elem = $("div");

console.log(elem.is("[class$='-annotation-visible']"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="<abc>-annotation-visible">test</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the classes of the targeted elements, split the classes into array and then manipulate the array to get desired results. Try this

```
const urlParams       = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const annotationTypes = urlParams?.get('annotypes')?.split(',') ?? [];

$(document).ready(function(){
    annotationTypes.forEach(annotype => {
        let visible   = `${annotype}-annotation-visible`;
        let invisible = `${annotype}-annotation-invisible`;
        let multiple  = "multiple-annotation-visible";

        $(`.${invisible}, .${visible}`).each(function(){
            let arr = [];
            $(this).attr('class').split(' ').forEach(cls => {
                if(cls === invisible){
                    arr.push(visible);
                }else if(cls === visible){
                    arr.push(multiple);
                }else{
                    arr.push(cls);
                }
            });
            $(this).attr('class', arr.join(' '));
        })
    })
});
```